# PHP Fatal error after layered navigation is activated

Tags: magento-1.7, layered-navigation, fatal-error

I would like to activate layered navigation in our multi-store magento 1.7.

As soon as I activate it in a category, the following exception appears in the error-log:

```
`Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object in /xxx/xxx/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php on line 192, referer: http://5.175.9.22/bs_de/vaporizer/zubehor/arizer-extreme-q`
```

Doesn't matter if our custom template or the modern template.
The code exits at the point where the first price block would be displayed.
We didn't made any modification in app/code/core/Mage.

What is going wrong? Any help?

Comment: It could be your third party modules.

Comment: show us those codes on that line. It seems that, that file is modified somehow. You should use a clean copy of that file in your application and then try again.

Comment: Most likely a 3rd party rewrite if no core changes: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by the Extension *FireGento_GermanSetup*, probably in combination with the Module *Eternal_AjaxFilter* of our Template Extension.

After removing/commenting this entry from /base/default/layout/germansetup.xml the problem was solved:

```
<action method="addPriceBlockType">
     <type>simple</type>
     <block>germansetup/baseprice</block>
     <template>baseprice/baseprice.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Indeed basesprices are working still.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `_getPriceBlockTemplate()` is not returning the proper block object. What's the product type of the first rendered item?

You'd check any modules you've installed, try disabling them at `app/etc/modules`

If the issue is fixed this way then you'd contact the conflicting module provider for support, as this error cannot occur in a fresh Magento installation